# Which pins do I need to connect on a DVI to make the screen stay on?

Tags: vga, dvi, lcd

I have an LCD panel screen with a broken LCD. However, my mother would like to have the backlight to use as a light box - for her art.

This is ideal - it's an excellent size but it has a frustratingly short timeout if it has no signal - after which it will go off completely.

Is there an easy (hardware) way of forcing this screen to stay on - ideally connecting two pins or holes on either the DVI or VGA.

Comment: @GiaRui It automatically powers off like many screens. I want to trick it into thinking it has a vga cable connected

Comment: Reverse engineering the monitor to find the inverter(dc/ac) which supply the lightpower, could be useful. Perhaps it depends on the model which pins to use. Or google for "turn monitor into lightbox".